# How do you set the default Reports folder in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting

In Classic, the default selection for the Reports tab is "All Reports" but that is not the case in Lightning Experience *or* when using the "Report List" component in a Community/Experience Cloud site. It always defaults to "Recent" which, for new users, displays an empty section.

There was a [Salesforce idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000adu9AAA) to set "All Reports" as the default that was seemingly delivered in 2012 (before LEX was a thing).

Is there a way to configure this setting in Lightning other than manipulating the Reports tab URL (I see that `?queryScope=everything` will select the All Items option)?

[image: Reports Tab in Salesforce]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, out of the box, to change this.

Your idea can be a workaround.

1. Hide "Report" tab on user's profiles
2. Create your own custom "Web" tab
3. Use the URL you see when clicking on "All Reports" - it'll be something like: `https://domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Report/home?queryScope=everything`
4. Give user's access to this custom tab and add to application's nav bar.

Otherwise, to get this added to the standard functionality, there's the following ideas (I've requested they be merged) you can upvote

1. [Pin Report Folder view as default (like in listviews for other objects)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LvPDQA0)
2. [Customizing the Default Reports page view](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PdyKQAS)
3. [Add a "Clear" option for the Recently Viewed in the Reports tab](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lglkQAA)